Huge mysql binary logs
Since the last Drupal 10.3 update, we have had the problem that the storage space fills up rapidly (1-2 GB per hour).
After a more detailed analysis, it became apparent that the /var/lib/mysql folder had inflated massively within a few hours. These are exclusively binary log files.
We did not change anything except for the Drupal update. The versions of the LAMP stack have not changed either.
We now delete the binary logs after a few hours, but this does not address the cause. How can this be fixed?

Are any tables rapidly growing?

No. The largest table is approx. 30MB in size.
The complete database is approx. 500MB. The binlog files take up 95% of the storage space under /var/lib/mysql

What does reading binary logs with mysqlbinlog indicate they contain in excess?

Did you enable state cache? https://www.drupal.org/node/3177901

Thank you, @PatrickKenny! I disabled the state cache and this resolves the issue!

@vincent.hoehn Glad it fixed your issue.  Note that the state cache will be permanently enabled in Drupal 11 so watch out when upgrading.

@PatrickKenny I have this same problem.  If the state cache is going to be made permanent, then it sounds like disabling it is not a proper or long-term solution to the problem of MySQL spewing out gigabytes of logs per day.  Is there no more reliable  solution than this?

No. Not without understanding what are all those state values rapidly changing on your sites.

@monalisa Thank you.  I posted a new question with that information.
