MySQL log files filling disk
I do not know much about Drupal.  I have a Drupal 10 installation using MySQL 8.0.37 on Ubuntu 22.04.  The Drupal site is the only thing running on this server.
MySQL is filling the /var/lib/mysql/ directory with binary log files of the form binlog.000572 at a rate of something like 50MB/hour.  Within a few days to a week, this fills the hard drive and threatens a system crash.
This question is more or less identical to this one.  The comments to that question indicate that the issue is Drupal 10's "state cache".  Unfortunately, the only suggested solution is to disable the state cache.  This is not a proper solution, since Drupal 10 seems to be designed by intention to use the state cache, and in fact Drupal 11 will make it mandatory and not disableable.  I'm in search of a proper solution to prevent Drupal from generating 50MB/hour of MySQL log files.
The linked drupal.org page for the Drupal 10 state cache gives a couple of tips for figuring out what's generating state cache-based log content.  Running these on my database for the Drupal 10 site gives
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(LENGTH(value)) FROM key_value WHERE collection = 'state';
+----------+--------------------+
| COUNT(*) | SUM(LENGTH(value)) |
+----------+--------------------+
|       25 |              11345 |
+----------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name, LENGTH(value) FROM key_value WHERE collection = 'state' ORDER BY LENGTH(value) DESC LIMIT 100;
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
| name                                  | LENGTH(value) |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
| routing.non_admin_routes              |          5695 |
| system.profile.files                  |          1650 |
| views.view_route_names                |          1434 |
| router.path_roots                     |          1006 |
| routing.menu_masks.router             |           556 |
| system.theme.files                    |           488 |
| twig_extension_hash_prefix            |           130 |
| system.cron_key                       |            82 |
| system.private_key                    |            82 |
| node.min_max_update_time              |            80 |
| install_time                          |            13 |
| update.last_check                     |            13 |
| simple_sitemap.last_cron_generate     |            13 |
| system.cron_last                      |            13 |
| system.css_js_query_string            |            13 |
| update.last_email_notification        |            13 |
| webform.version                       |            12 |
| install_task                          |            11 |
| comment.node_comment_statistics_scale |             9 |
| migrate_tools_sync                    |             6 |
| field.storage.deleted                 |             6 |
| field.field.deleted                   |             6 |
| webform.element.message               |             6 |
| system.maintenance_mode               |             4 |
| comment.maintain_entity_statistics    |             4 |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+


Since I'm not a Drupal programmer, these mean nothing to me, but I hope someone here can deduce something from them.  Based on these, what should be my next troubleshooting step?
Aside from the linked drupal.SE question, everything else I can find on this error comes up for Drupal 6.  Was there anything that happened in Drupal 6 that might have regressed or recurred for Drupal 10?
Edit: The log files are so large that they're difficult for me to scan through without something to grep for.  Here's a sample from near the beginning of one log; there are many rows like this:
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5587775 CRC32 0x0413cc3c      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5587775
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5593669 CRC32 0x03e6424d      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5593669
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5601413 CRC32 0x717fba95      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5601413
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5614484 CRC32 0x68663b12      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5614484
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5621579 CRC32 0xb1a2fa47      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5621579
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5629561 CRC32 0x3d26e53f      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5629561
#240723  4:28:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 5636692 CRC32 0x322da116      Delete_rows: table id 116
# at 5636692

Here's a sample from a little later:
BINLOG '
l2mfZhMBAAAAVwAAAJYBAAAAAHQAAAAAAAEAC3F1YXJrbmV0ZDEwAAxjYWNoZV9yZW5kZXIABw/8
CPYC/A8I/wAEDgME/wAiAQEAAwZBP/z/AAuSWl5A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This huge block of random letters is so large that when I try to scroll through it in nano, I can't scroll past the end of it before getting tired and giving up.
Do these mean anything useful?

What does reading binary logs with mysqlbinlog indicate the binary logs contain in excess?

The count of values is useful but only an understanding of what is in the binary logs will lead to a factual answer. If it’s to do with state, some state values may be rapidly changing.

@monalisa Thanks for your response, I've edited my question with some samples from the logs.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322041/how-to-solve-increasing-size-of-mysql-binlog-files-problem

@monalisa I had seen that link.  The only solutions there are to manually purge the logs every day, which is not a reasonable or proper solution, or to keep fewer logs.  I want to have the logs, I just want to have them not filled with GB of junk like the endless field of characters in my last edit.  I assume Drupal is prompting that log output, since it doesn't happen in any of my other MySQL 8 installations, so I'm looking for a Drupal solution.

Given you don't want to disable binary logging because you use the binary logs for point-in-time database restores, replication, or some other use-case, and are not backing up the databases in such a way that the binary log purges itself, then, yes, someone has to figure out what inside the logs is excessive. If disabling state cache limits binary log growth, it is a reasonable conclusion that this question is identical to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/320350/huge-mysql-binary-logs and you or someone has to determine which state values are constantly changing.

Additionally can you confirm whether the site uses the default database caching mechanisms or alternatives. Database caching naturally results in a lot of writes and deletes.
